# How can I Robocopy between servers and just manage the deltas without destroying existing content?

Tags: windows, powershell, robocopy

I've been playing around a bit with Robocopy on my local machine, and I'd like to do it between different servers now. I've stood up a server and created a blank folder called "Test2." On my local machine, I have a folder called "Test1" containing an image file.

I'd like to Robocopy the folder's contents from my local machine (Test1) to the folder in the server (Test2).

I tried: **Robocopy C:\Users\me\Desktop\Test1 \testserver01\C:\Users\me\Desktop\Test2 /mir /copyall /dcopy:T**

Once the image file from Test1 makes it to Test2 on the server, I will add another image file to Test1, and delete the previously existing one. I'd like to then do another Robocopy from Test1 to Test2, but, I don't want the already existing image in Test2 to be deleted. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: You might look at using `rsync` - it has a `--delete` option to delete files from destination that are no longer on source.

Comment: That's the thing, I don't want to delete the files from the destination that are no longer in source. I want to keep them there in destination.

Comment: In that case with rsync you'd simply skip that option....

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the /MIR or /PURGE options and you should be good.  Test this with test data before you trust the results.